# How to properly cite an incorrect result?

Tags: citations

This should be a common problem, but I could not find anything on Google ([This question](https://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/151391/what-to-do-about-a-citation-that-may-be-wrong) is relevant, but it is not quite the same).

I am writting a math paper where I prove a result, let's call it X.

This result was previously established (not once) in the special case p=2 by other people, and in my work I have generalized for general prime p, using different methods.

It is a common practice to cite related results. One of these results is a ~12 years old paper that was published only on arXiv. In that paper they prove the case p=2 by first proving X in the connected case and then reducing matters from the general case to the connected case. This reduction was more of a sketch (4 lines) and in the Appendix of the paper. However, I am convinced that this reduction is logically incomplete. More specifically, I tried, while proving the general case to take the approach described in these four lines and see if I can adapt it to work, but I could not, so right now I believe this approach can not work even with additional effort.

I contacted the author, but received no reply.

What is the right approach in this case? I thought of two options

1. I cite the paper claiming that the author only proved the theorem in the connected case.
2. I give full credit to the author, but write that I could not verify the reduction from the general case to the connected case.

But both of them seems problematic to me, as the author did not approve the mistake. Do you have any other ideas?

Comment: Given that this hasn't been published in a peer reviewed journal for 12 years, I wonder whether you need to mention it at all. I probably wouldn't, and I'd suspect that others (reviewers when this was submitted to a journal) have already seen that the approach doesn't work. (Of course a reviewer may ask to discuss it, but such a thing won't lead to rejection.)

Comment: @ChristianHennig Thank you. I think I should have also mentioned that I am also somewhat afraid of getting on the bad side of the said author. Although, I mentioned there were other authors who proved this result and now I see they did not cite that paper as well.

Answer (score 2):

First, you don't need an author's permission to make a statement that their result is incorrect.

Second, if you want to make such a claim, then you'd better be sure of what you say, just for your own reputation.

I suggest that you spend the additional effort to either verify their result or have clear proof that it doesn't work, such as a counterexample.

For either of your sample citations, you might want to say a few more words in any case about why you make such a claim.

Comment: Buffy thank you very much for your answer. I think I should have mentioned I am afraid of getting on the bad side of that author. Does it follow from your answer that there is no diplomatic approach in this situation?